# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 10485760 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2186 bytes)

Tags: php, html

Que al gente! Tengo este problema. Ya intente lo del php.ini y no me funciona. Al parecer tengo algún problema en el código pero no logro darme cuenta. Y soy muy nuevo en esto. en el Error me marca la linea 26 seria esta

```
$original_imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($temporal_imagen);
```

Este es el resto del codigo

```
$ruta = "img/articulos-img/";
$ruta_miniatura = $ruta."/miniaturas/";

function recortar($temporal,$imagen){
    global $ruta_miniatura;
    $temporal_imagen = $temporal;
    $nombre_imagen = $imagen;

    $extension_imagen = end(explode(".", $nombre_imagen));

    //Abrir la foto original
    if ($extension_imagen == "jpg"){
        $original_imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($temporal_imagen);
    }else {
        $original_imagen = imagecreatefrompng($temporal_imagen);
    }

    $ancho_original =imagesx($original_imagen);
    $alto_original =imagesy($original_imagen);
    //Crear un lienzo vacio
    $copia_imagen = imagecreatetruecolor(400,424);

    //copiar original en el lienzo copia
    imagecopyresampled($copia_imagen, $original_imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0, 400, 424, $ancho_original, $alto_original);
    //Exportar imagen 

    if ($extension_imagen == "jpg"){
        imagejpeg($copia_imagen,$ruta_miniatura.$nombre_imagen,100);
    }else {
        imagepng($copia_imagen,$ruta_miniatura.$nombre_imagen,9);
    }

    return $ruta_miniatura.$nombre_imagen;
}

function rearrange( $arr ){
foreach( $arr as $key => $all ){
    foreach( $all as $i => $val ){
        $new[$i][$key] = $val;    
    }    
}
return $new;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_FILES)) {
    $fotos = rearrange($_FILES['fotos']);

    $miniatura = recortar($fotos[0]['tmp_name'],$fotos[0]['name']);

    $statement = $conexion->prepare('
        INSERT INTO articulos (titulo,descripcion,precio,descuento,miniatura)
         VALUES (:titulo,:descripcion,:precio,:descuento,:miniatura)
    ');

    $statement->execute(array(
        ':titulo' => $_POST['titulo'],
        ':descripcion' => $_POST['descripcion'],
        ':precio' => $_POST['precio'],
        ':descuento' => $_POST['descuento'],
        ':miniatura' => $miniatura
    ));

    $statement = $conexion->prepare('
        SELECT idArticulo FROM `articulos` WHERE titulo = :titulo && precio= :precio
    ');

    $statement->execute(array(
        ':titulo' => $_POST['titulo'],
        ':precio' => $_POST['precio']
    ));

    $resultado = $statement->fetch();
    $idArticulo = $resultado['idArticulo'];





    for($i = 0; $i<count($fotos); $i++ ){
        if ($fotos[$i]['name']) {
            move_uploaded_file($fotos[$i]['tmp_name'], $ruta.$fotos[$i]['name']);
            $statement = $conexion->prepare('
                INSERT INTO imagenes (ruta,idArticulo)
                 VALUES (:ruta,:idArticulo)
            ');

            $statement->execute(array(
                ':ruta' => $ruta.$fotos[$i]['name'],
                ':idArticulo' => $idArticulo
            ));

        }

    }
```

Probe algunas cosas pero no logro dar con la solucion. Me pasa co0n muchos archivos, hasta lo que no se exeden.

Comment: El error se produce porque el script consume una cantidad de memoria excesiva, nada que ver con los tamaños de los ficheros. El problema lo tienes con alguno de los bucles que se repite sin parar hasta que no hay más memoria disponible. Puedes crear condiciones forzadas de finalización para detectar en cuál ocurre, por ejemplo que cada bucle se ejecute un máximo de 100 veces y la pones uno por uno hasta que lo encuentres.

Comment: Puedes probar a aumentar la memoria, por ejemplo: `ini_set('memory_limit, '256M');`.

Comment: Prueba usar `imagedestroy($copia_imagen);` antes de retornar de la funció n `recortar`

Comment: Más tarde voy a probar con imagededtroy() suena bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando `imagedestroy($copia_imagen);` como dijo amenadiel se solucionó. Parece que el script utiliza mucha memoria.

Saludos y gracias!!